# Is there a bug in PdfPTable in iText 5.5.4+?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

There seems to be a bug since iText 5.5.4 or at least a change in default behavior when working with tables and the setComplete() method.

If I run the code below with iText 5.5.4 the resulting pdf will have pages with exactly 20 rows per page (except the last page but one). Same results with iText 5.5.5. With iText 5.5.3 the number of rows per page was fitted to the height of the page resulting in a smaller number of total pages.

Here is an example program to reproduce the behavior:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PdfPTableTest {

    private File file;
    private Font font;

    private Random rand;

    public PdfPTableTest() {
        file = new File("out.pdf");
        rand = new Random();
        font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI,
                BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK, true);
    }

    public void run() {
        try (
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)
            )
        {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, bos);
            document.addTitle("itext PdfPTable setComplete() test");
            document.addCreator("test");
            document.addAuthor("test");
            document.addSubject("test");

            document.open();

            float[] widths = new float[] {50f, 50f};
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(widths.length);
            table.setComplete(false);
            table.setWidths(widths);
            table.setWidthPercentage(100);

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column #1", font));
            table.addCell(cell);
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column #2", font));
            table.addCell(cell);
            table.setHeaderRows(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table cell #" + i, font));
                table.addCell(cell);
                String s = getRandomText();
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(s, font));
                table.addCell(cell);
                if (i % 20 == 0) {
                    document.add(table);
                }
            }

            table.setComplete(true);
            document.add(table);
            document.close();

        } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getRandomText() {
        int length = rand.nextInt(100);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (i % 15 == 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            sb.append(Integer.valueOf(rand.nextInt(10)));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PdfPTableTest pdfTest = new PdfPTableTest();
        pdfTest.run();
    }

}
```

If I increase the max. length of the random generated text to 120 characters

```
int length = rand.nextInt(120);
```

then also an exception gets thrown:

```
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Infinite table loop; row content is larger than the page (for instance because you didn't scale an image).
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:809)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:278)
    at de.itext.test.PdfPTableTest.run(PdfPTableTest.java:69)
    at de.itext.test.PdfPTableTest.main(PdfPTableTest.java:96)
Caused by: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Infinite table loop; row content is larger than the page (for instance because you didn't scale an image).
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(PdfDocument.java:2679)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:750)
    ... 3 more
```

In iText 5.5.3 there is no exception and the pdf looks fine (resulting in cells with 3 separate lines).

Can anyone confirm that this is a bug (that will get fixed in a future release)?

Comment: I have tested with iText 5.5.5 (officially released tomorrow, but already available on SourceForge) and I executed my example multiple times without getting any exception. However: the resulting PDF didn't look the way I expected. There are only 20 rows per page.

Comment: Aha, I changed 20 into 30 and now I get the exception. I'll investigate. I assume that you're not a customer, so this may get low priority.

Comment: If you change the integer in the method getRandomText() from 100 into 120 or larger you also get the exception. The unexpected number of rows per page came with itext 5.5.4, I assume changelog "An incomplete PdfPTable would sometimes ignore headers and drop the first rows of each page."

Comment: You are right. Revision 6630 breaks your example, but if I revert revision 6630, I break our tests. I have created a ticket in our internal issue tracker and I've assigned it to the person who committed revision 6630.